# Joda DateTime in the Play Framework and Form Mapping

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime, playframework-2.2

I have a field in the database that has a data type of DateTime's. I am trying to map my form helper to a Joda DateTime. I have that part down:

```
  val transForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "startTime" -> jodaDate,
      "endTime" -> jodaDate
    )(TransactionFormData.apply)(TransactionFormData.unapply)
  )
```

The problem occurs when I am trying to get the data from the flash scope:

```
      flash.get("startTime").getOrElse(DateTime.parse("01-01-1969")), //need a fall back default value
      flash.get("endTime").getOrElse(DateTime.parse("01-01-1969")),
```

Here is the error I receive on compile time:

```
type mismatch; found : Comparable[_ >: String with org.joda.time.ReadableInstant <: Comparable[_ >: String with org.joda.time.ReadableInstant <: Object]] with java.io.Serializable required: org.joda.time.DateTime
```

any ideas on how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a brain fart, here is the solution:

```
      DateTime.parse(flash.get("startTime").getOrElse("01-01-1969")),
      DateTime.parse(flash.get("endTime").getOrElse("01-01-1969")),
```